# How to use local fonts in react-boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-boilerplate

Can anyone recommend a simple way to incorporate local fonts in to Max Stoiber's [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate) ? I'm a webpack / css modules / PostCSS noob and am finding the set-up difficult. Any guidance with regard to structure would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Does this help you? https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/pull/473 . I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like font imports should go in `app/containers/App/styles.css`, along with the other global styles. Since the banner logo is in `app/containers/App`, it looks like `react-boilerplate` prefers that images and fonts go there, so I would put your font files there and add the CSS import in `styles.css`.